# Python RegEx matching substrings on various conditions

Tags: python, regex

Been struggling with this one for a while now - I simply can't wrap my brain around it.

Given the following string variations:

```
some text
some text http://a.link.to/something
some text - http://a.link.to/something
some text: http://a.link.to/something
http://a.link.to/something
```

I am looking for a RegEx that would produce the following:

```
{'text': 'some text',
 'link': ''}

{'text': 'some text',
 'link': 'http://a.link.to/something'}

{'text': '',
 'link': 'http://a.link.to/something'}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/iT8jB4/1) help? Here's what it produces: http://ideone.com/FL1ehX

Comment: Works on regex101.com but it raises an error when I try to use it with re.search: invalid expression, bad character range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use named capturing groups in re.match function so that you could be able to create dictionary  with  user defined keys.

```
>>> s = '''some text
some text http://a.link.to/something
some text - http://a.link.to/something
some text: http://a.link.to/something
http://a.link.to/something'''
>>> for i in s.split('\n'):
        re.match(r'(?P<text>(?:(?!http://).)*?)\W*\b(?P<link>http://.*)?$', i).groupdict()


{'link': None, 'text': 'some text'}
{'link': 'http://a.link.to/something', 'text': 'some text'}
{'link': 'http://a.link.to/something', 'text': 'some text'}
{'link': 'http://a.link.to/something', 'text': 'some text'}
{'link': 'http://a.link.to/something', 'text': ''}
```

Comment: Looks like I'm missing something. The last string isn't quite right: `{'text': 'http://a.link.to/something', 'link': None}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(.+?)(http.*)?$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS4nV4/1)**

[image]

As you can see is not fully achieving what you want for the case of:

```
some text - http://a.link.to/something
```

Since it generates:

```
{'text': 'some text - ',  'link': 'http://a.link.to/something'}
                    ^--- Dash here
```

But you can do a pre or post clean to the text.

I'm posting the answer since it might help you.